# How can i move desription of magento 2 products outside the main container? ( for landing page)

Tags: magento2, product

I want to make every product page a nice landing page with full width like you can see on one plus 3 website.

https://oneplus.net/3

So i want the products image and the right colum where you buy the product to be fixed. But when you scroll down it's full width. (the long descprition div is full width). Then i can do things like on one plus site.

Problem: Everything is inside the maincontainer which controls the width...

I would like to get it out of it, so i can then do what i want.

I tried css tricks "to make child div bigger then parrent div" without success.

Thanks in advance!